# How to moderate facebook comment plugin with Graph API calls?

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments, facebook-social-plugins

Moderation of facebook comments is done thanks to its moderation tools which require to be connected to the business manager of the facebook account.

My need is to retrieve these comments with api graph requests to save them in the database and moderate them in the same way through the api graph without using the plugin's moderation tools, this is the way I use to moderate comments on my facebook pages.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an endpoint to delete, hide or approve a comment through a POST request.

Does anyone have a method to do it? Is there an endpoint I don't know that allows it?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on any comment to get the permanent link. Then query it via Graph Explorer with endpoint: `GET {Object-ID}/comments`

Comment: Thank you for your response
I need to make POST requests to hide a comment as follows:
`curl -XPOST \
     -k \
     -F 'is_hidden=true' \
     -F 'access_token=[access_token]' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/ [comment_id]

`
or DELETE to delete it 
The GET request I already use it to retrieve the messages.

Comment: Yes it works, but I have no problem te retrieve comments, my need is to moderate this comments with api graph call without using moderat tools

Comment: @LotfiZaouai Hey, i mean that did you try to use POST request to modify the comment? This is the only document Facebook provided for comment object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/comment#updating

Other than this, it could be a feature request

Comment: Yes indeed, when it's a facebook page comment, we can all make it, like it, delete it or hide it ..etc if I have the permissions. but with a facebook comments code, we can't make post requests.